# MySQL - BETWEEN clause not working properly with DATETIME

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a database where it is stored the date of creation of the record. The problem is that when I try to `SELECT` all records within 1 year, I get no rows returned.

I created a SQLFiddle to illustrate what I have and what I'm trying to do: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/33a32b/8

```
SELECT aux.description, DATE_FORMAT(aux.date_creation, '%d/%m/%Y às %H:%i') AS `formatted_date`
  FROM aux
  WHERE aux.date_creation BETWEEN 'CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR' AND 'CURDATE()'
  ORDER BY `formatted_date` DESC;
```

Comment: You should put your code also here. SQLFiddle is not always online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT aux.description, DATE_FORMAT(aux.date_creation, '%d/%m/%Y às %H:%i') AS `formatted_date`
FROM aux
WHERE aux.date_creation BETWEEN 'CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR' AND 'CURDATE()'
ORDER BY `formatted_date` DESC;
```

The single quotes are incorrect.  You have a string constant, not a date expression.  Presumably, `date_creation` is in the past, so all you need is:

```
SELECT aux.description,
       DATE_FORMAT(aux.date_creation, '%d/%m/%Y às %H:%i') AS formatted_date
FROM aux
WHERE aux.date_creation >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR
ORDER BY aux.date_creation DESC;
```

Note that I also changed the `ORDER BY`.  Normally, one wants Jan 2nd to follow Jan 1st, not Feb 1st.

Comment: I was using the functions within the single quotes and was getting no problem. That just happened with this single query. Weird stuff. Thanks a lot, man!